# Array is non-null in JavaScript but null in PHP's $_POST after Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I'm trying to make a simple download counting script that sends data to a MySQL database. I make an associative array which I send through Ajax to a PHP script, however, although I have confirmed that the array contains what I put into it in the JavaScript, the $_POST variable is empty in my PHP.

This is what my JavaScript function looks like:

```
function download(name) {
    var post = {};
    post['fileName'] = name;
    $.ajax({
        url: "phpScripts/downloadCounter.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: post
    });
    window.location = "downloads/" + name;
}
```

Then, within my PHP script (downloadCounter.php) I have this to check the $_POST variable:

```
ob_start();
var_dump($_POST);
error_log(ob_get_clean());
error_log($_POST["fileName"]);
```

The var_dump posts an array of length 0 and the attempt at retrieving the data directly results in an error saying that the index "fileName" is undefined.

The page in question is http://strongjoshua.com/projects/software/line_counter. Upon pressing the download button Chrome reports a POST to the script file with return code 302 (file found), a GET of the actual downloading file, and finally another GET for the script again. **This makes it seem like the POST request only reaches as far as finding the file and not actually executing it...** Why/how is this happening?

I have done that form of an Ajax request before and it has always worked, so I am at a lost as to why it is not working now. I am using PHP 5.6 on a server hosted by [EasyDNS](http://easydns.com)'s web hosting.

Comment: Check the browser developer tools to see what the outgoing HTTP request looks like.

Comment: Well starting an XHR right before you reload the page is not really a safe bet; the browser isn't going to wait for the XHR to complete, but the server *should* get it. You should be able to tell what the POST parameters look like in the HTTP request information from the developer console, and if you have server-side logging you can see what's received there.

Comment: But that doesn't reload the page? It only downloads the file. Or am I misunderstanding this? The page does not change (although I do understand that I am technically redirecting), only the file is downloaded. If this is the error, then how else would I have the client download something (idk if I want the success function to be the download in case their is a database error, I still want the user to be able to download)?

Comment: Oh oh I see - your "download" link sets the Content-Disposition header, right? OK, never mind then. In any case, I'd still look at the HTTP request information to confirm that your outgoing HTTP request contains what you think it does.

Comment: @Pointy I don't even know what a Content-Disposition header is :3 But the POST header that I described contains the actual array, but of course, the GET request does not.

Comment: _“Upon pressing the download button Chrome reports a POST to the script file with return code 302 (file found)”_ – so where does that redirect come from – is it from your script that is supposed to process the POST data, _after_ it has done that processing? If not, and you are only redirecting _to_ the script that is supposed to do that, then that’s your problem right there: The browser follows the redirect by issuing a _GET_ request, and therefor the POST data is lost.

Comment: That issue aside, I would not bet on every browser making/finishing your AJAX request, when you change the location simultaneously. It would be safer to only do that in the callback of your AJAX call. (Or not even use AJAX at all – but simply call a script that counts the download, and then redirects to the URL of the download file itself.)

Comment: @CBroe I even tried putting the actual download (the window.location redirect) within the success and error functions of the ajax request (so the download would happen no matter what), but the same thing occurs, which makes little sense to me. Could post an answer detailing the solution you proposed? Because I am unsure how I would go about it.

Comment: You need to address the issue from my comment before first – if you redirect before the POST data is processed, then you will lose that POST data. Do you have any kind of automatic redirect (mod_rewrite) set up, that would redirect from an URL with a `.php` suffix to the suffix-less version or something?

Comment: `http://strongjoshua.com/projects/software/line_counter.php` seems to exist on your server, but redirects to `http://strongjoshua.com/projects/software/line_counter` automatically – so I assume it’s the same thing with your counter script. If your server is set up to use `http://strongjoshua.com/phpScripts/downloadCounter` as the script address – then use that in your AJAX call in the first place.

Comment: Yes, my .htaccess redirects .php files to their suffix-less counterparts (hence the lack of a suffix in the link I posted). Is this causing the data to be lost? If so, how do I prevent that (would putting a blank .htaccess in the phpScripts folder suffice)?

Comment: You don’t need to prevent it, you just have to make your AJAX request to that “final” address in the first place.

Comment: Wow. That works! Post that as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is set up to automatically redirect a request for
`http://strongjoshua.com/phpScripts/downloadCounter.php`
to
`http://strongjoshua.com/phpScripts/downloadCounter`

Now, because the browser uses method GET to follow such redirects, when your script is finally “called”, there is no POST data any more.

Simply change

```
$.ajax({
    url: "phpScripts/downloadCounter.php",
```

to use the “correct” address in the first place,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "phpScripts/downloadCounter",
```

– that way, the server will not need to redirect to the “final” address first, the request method that your script is called with *stays* POST – and you get your data in `$_POST` as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
<script>
function download(name) {

var postData = 
            {
                "fileName":name
            }
$.ajax({
    url: "phpScripts/downloadCounter.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {myData:postData},
    success: function(output_string){ 
        alert(output_string);
    }
});

//window.location = "downloads/" + name;
}
download('Counter Strike');

</script>
```

PHP

```
 <?php
 echo $_POST['myData']['fileName'];
 ?>
```

Running that script should alert "Counter Strike"

Comment: I don't understand how this is different from what I did. All you did was put the post array within another array and pass that. Why would that make a difference? It didn't btw.

Comment: I tested it, that's why I posted. @StrongJoshua

Comment: You commented out the actual download. And I think that's the problem. Check my last comment on my question.